Proving homomorphism property of commutative totally ordered groups
Definition: a commutative group $\Gamma$ with a total order $\leq$, s.t. $\gamma\leq\gamma^{\prime}\Rightarrow\gamma\delta\leq\gamma^{\prime}\delta,\quad\text{for all }\gamma,\gamma^{\prime},\delta\in\Gamma $
Definition: a homomorphism of totally ordered groups is a homomorphism $f : Γ → Γ′$ of groups s.t. for all $γ_1, γ_2 ∈ Γ$ one has $γ_1 ≤ γ_2 ⇒ f(γ_1) ≤ f(γ_2).$
I want to prove the following preposition:

Let $\Gamma , \Gamma'$ be totally ordered groups. A group homomorphism $f: \Gamma \to \Gamma ^{\prime }$ is a homomorphism of totally ordered groups if and only if for all $\gamma\in\Gamma$ with $\gamma<1$ one has $f(\gamma)<1',$ where $1$ is identity of $\Gamma$ and $1'$ is identity of $\Gamma'$.

My partial proof:
($⇒$) (If $f : Γ → Γ′$, then for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ with $\gamma<1$, we have $f(\gamma)<1'$)

Since $f$ is homomorphism, $γ_1 ≤ γ_2 ⇒ f(γ_1) ≤ f(γ_2),$ i.e. $γ_1 < γ_1 ⇒ f(γ_1) < f(γ_2)$ or  $γ_1 = γ_1 ⇒ f(γ_1) = f(γ_2)$. Since we have $\gamma<1$, $⇒ f(γ) < f(1)=1'$.

I was told this approach is not correct, since we need to check for injectivity.
($⇐$) (If for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$ with $\gamma<1$ we have $f(\gamma)<1'$, then $f$ is homomorphism of totally ordered groups $f : Γ → Γ′$)
I am also having trouble proving this in the opposite direction. I tried writing it up into cases like: $\gamma_1 \leq \gamma_2 \leq 1$, $\gamma_1 = \gamma_2 = 1$, $\gamma_1 \geq 1 \leq \gamma_2$, etc. but I am not so sure about it.
How do I prove this preposition?

You say $\gamma_1 < \gamma_2\implies f(\gamma_1)<f(\gamma_2)$. You proof is slightly incomplete. It needs justification for as to why $f(\gamma_1)\neq f(\gamma_2)$. I.e. you need to justify why totally ordered group homomorphisms are injective (if they even are, I'm not sure).

@Jakobian The way I understood this is that $\gamma_1\leq\gamma_2\Rightarrow f(\gamma_1)\leq f(\gamma_2)$ is made up of two cases 1) $\gamma_{1}<\gamma_{1}\Rightarrow f(\gamma_{1})<f(\gamma_{2})$ and 2) $\gamma_1=\gamma_1\Rightarrow f(\gamma_1)=f(\gamma_2).$ Or am I misunderstanding something here?

You are. This is not what it means. I'm not sure what you mean that it's "made up" out of two cases, or how would you justify that it means the same thing.

In fact, an obvious homomorphism of totally ordered groups is $f:\mathbb{R}\to {0}$ given by $f(x) = 0$, and it doesn't satisfy $x < 0 \implies f(x) < 0$. What you want to prove is false.

@Jakobian Yeah if that's the case, then my approach is not correct. But I am not sure how to approach it differently. Is there something we can say from $\gamma_1\leq\gamma_2\Rightarrow f(\gamma_1)\leq f(\gamma_2)$ at all?

You can say that, for group homomorphisms, $\gamma_1\leq \gamma_2 \implies f(\gamma_1)\leq f(\gamma_2)$ is equivalent to $\gamma\leq 1\implies f(\gamma)\leq 1$. Just do what Joseph Harrison did in the answer below.

Ok, now that I think about it, are we allowed to go this route: Since $\gamma < 1$, we can write this as 1) $\gamma \leq 1$ and 2) $\gamma \neq 1$. From 1) it follows $f(\gamma) \leq 1'$ Now we only have to prove that $f(\gamma) \neq 1'$? Or total order doesn't work like usual inequalities? (I am new to this)

What you said is true. But you can't prove that $f(\gamma)\neq 1'$. Please consider what I wrote above. The zero function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 0$, is a totally ordered group homomorphism for which $x < 0$ doesn't imply $f(x) < 0$. What you want to prove is false.

Moreover, note that there are different notions of "totally ordered group". What you probably mean is a bi-ordered groups. See wikipedia.

So your example shows $f(\gamma) \leq 1'$ doesn't guarantee $f(\gamma)<1'$, since in your case $f(\gamma)=1$ for all $\gamma$, even when $\gamma<1$?

Yes, exactly, if $\Gamma, \Gamma'$ are any bi-ordered groups then the map $f:\Gamma\to \Gamma'$ given by $f(\gamma) = 1'$ is always a homomorphism of bi-ordered groups, so you can't prove that $\gamma < 1\implies f(\gamma) < 1$, since whenever $\Gamma$ has more than one element, there is such element $\gamma$ so that $\gamma < 1$, yet we have $f(\gamma) = 1$

The appropriate statement you would like to prove, is that a group homomorphism $f:\Gamma\to \Gamma'$ between bi-ordered groups $\Gamma, \Gamma'$ is a bi-ordered group homomorphism, if and only if, $\gamma \leq 1$ implies $f(\gamma)\leq 1$ for all $\gamma\in \Gamma$.

Sorry, I see now what you are working with are commutative totally ordered groups, so my remark about bi-ordered groups didn't matter.

Apologies if I'm missing something.
Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in \Gamma$ with $\gamma_1 \leq \gamma_2$. If $\gamma_1 = \gamma_2$ then $f(\gamma_1) \leq f(\gamma_2)$ a fortiori, so assume $\gamma_1 < \gamma_2$. Since $\Gamma$ is totally ordered, $\gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1} < 1$ and by assumption $f(\gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1}) < 1'$. Now $f(\gamma_1)f(\gamma_2)^{-1} < 1'$ since $f$ is a group homomorphism, so $f(\gamma_1) < f(\gamma_2)$ since $\Gamma'$ is a totally ordered group. Then $f$ is a homomorphism of totally ordered groups.

Thanks, can you elaborate how we go from $f(\gamma_1)f(\gamma_2)^{-1}<1'$ to $f(\gamma_1)<f(\gamma_2)$ though?

@AndrésdeFonollosa I am taking $\delta = f(\gamma_2)$ in your definition of a totally ordered group. Thus $f(\gamma_1)f(\gamma_2)^{-1} < 1'$ implies $f(\gamma_1)f(\gamma_2)^{-1}f(\gamma_2) < f(\gamma_2)$ etc.

So is this the fact that in totally ordered group G', $\alpha\beta^{-1}<1^{\prime}$ for elements is $\alpha,\beta\in G'$ implies $\alpha<\beta$?

@AndrésdeFonollosa yes
